# Python _thread Have each thread process the respective number in a sequence

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I want the first thread to process the first one and the fifth and the ninth, the second would get the second-sixth-tenth, third-seventh, eleventh, and the fourth would the eighth and twelfth. I know that it is a repeating patterning of (4*counter + original) but I am lost when it comes to moving that actual _thread process. Here is what I have so far.
If I am going about it wrong them just tell me because I am open to suggestions.

Edit- I am using Python 3.3

```
def calc(threadName):
    testRange = 100
    testNumber = 100
    timesToTest = 25
    testCounter = 0
    if threadName  == 'ThreadOne':
        testNumber = (testNumber)   + 5*(testCounter)
    if threadName == 'ThreadTwo':
        testNumber = (testNumber+1) + 5*(testCounter)
    if threadName == 'ThreadThree':
        testNumber = (testNumber+2) + 5*(testCounter)
    if threadName == 'ThreadFour':
        testNumber = (testNumber+3) + 5*(testCounter)

    while testCounter < timesToTest:
        testCounter +=1
        while testRange >= 0:
            answer = ((testNumber*3) - ((testNumber-1)**2))
            testbool = isprime(answer)
            print('Testing '+str(testNumber)+' on '+str(threadName))
            testNumber +=1
            testRange -= 1
            if testbool:
                list.append((threadName,testNumber,answer))


threadOne = _thread.start_new_thread(calc,('ThreadOne', ))
threadTwo = _thread.start_new_thread(calc,('ThreadTwo', ))
threadThree = _thread.start_new_thread(calc,('ThreadThree', ))
threadFour = _thread.start_new_thread(calc,('ThreadFour', ))

while 1:
    pass
```

tried This:

```
import threading
import queue

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    global results_list
    print('in main class')
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.jobs_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.results_list = list()
        print('in init')

    def isprime(self,n):
        n = abs(int(n))
        print('in isprime')
        if n < 2:
            return False
        if n == 2:
            return True

        if not n & 1:
            return False

        for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
        return True

    def run(self):
        print('in run')
        while True:
            testNumber = self.jobs_queue.get()
            if testNumber == "END":
                return
                # here, do your stuff with 'testNumber'
            # for example, let's multiply it by 2
            answer = ((testNumber**3) - ((testNumber-1)**3))
            testbool = self.isprime(answer)
            if testbool:# results are appended to a list
                self.results_list.append((self.name,testNumber,answer))
    def calc(self, n):
        print('in calc')
        self.jobs_queue.put(n)
        if not self.is_alive():
            self.start()
    def get_result(self):
        print('in get_result')
        return self.results_list
    def stop(self):
        print('in stop')
        # tell the thread to stop,
        # once jobs in queue are done
        self.jobs_queue.put("END")
        self.join()
print('Anything')
workers = [Worker('thread 1'), Worker('thread 2'), Worker('thread 3'), Worker('thread 4')]

for n in range(100):
    print('here 1')
    w = workers[n % 4]
    w.calc(n)

for w in workers:
    w.stop()

for w in workers:
    x=1
    # print(results_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want a pool of 4 worker threads, fair queuing the same "job"
between those 4 threads.

I would do something more like that:

```
import threading
import queue

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.jobs_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.results_list = list()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            testNumber = self.jobs_queue.get()
            if testNumber == "END":
                return
            # here, do your stuff with 'testNumber'
            # for example, let's multiply it by 2
            answer = testNumber * 2
            # results are appended to a list
            self.results_list.append((self.name,testNumber,answer))
    def calc(self, n):
        self.jobs_queue.put(n)
        if not self.is_alive():
            self.start()
    def get_result(self):
        return self.results_list
    def stop(self):
        # tell the thread to stop,
        # once jobs in queue are done
        self.jobs_queue.put("END")
        self.join()

workers = [Worker('thread 1'), Worker('thread 2'), Worker('thread 3'), Worker('thread 4')]

for n in range(100):
    w = workers[n % 4]
    w.calc(n)

for w in workers:
    w.stop()

for w in workers:
    print(w.get_result())
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I understand little to none of. I was using the _thread module to stay away from the threading module. I appreciate the quick reply but have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Why staying away from the threading module? What doesn't work? Could you please tell what the error message is. What exactly you don't understand? I would be pleased to explain a bit more.

Comment: I was trying to avoid because it is my first time trying to thread a program and couldn't find any tutorials or examples for 3.3. I was trying to use _thread because it was a basic solution to basic problem.


Also it doesn't work because of the syntax at the end is not compatible with 3.3

Comment: I edited the code, tested it ; it works with 3.3 ; I added some comments. Hopefully you will understand.

Comment: Nope... Maybe you're confused because the results are displayed per thread (all results for thread 1, then all results for thread 2, etc.). Anyway, it's not a lot of code my advice for you is to study it a bit and you will understand. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry my file was referencing was old file on import instead of the module

Comment: Ok... So: does it help? I hope you can adapt it for you.

Comment: Yes it does work and I did adapt. Thank you for help but right now I am gonna see if there are any other answers about _thread module and if there isn't then I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Hi again ;) I am curious: did you have other answers or did you find any other way of achieving your task?

Comment: Nope I just forgot. Yours is now the answer!